# Updating map value for a specific key in Kotlin

Tags: dictionary, kotlin

I am new at Kotlin and trying to catch up the language.

I have a function that returns DayofWeek as a key and an Int as a value.

The issue that I am facing is that I need to take a list of object that has another list of object inside that has an Int value which I need to save and increment for every time I see the same value.

Here is my function -

```
class OrdersAnalyzer {
    data class Order(val orderId: Int, val creationDate: LocalDateTime, val orderLines: List<OrderLine>)

    data class OrderLine(val productId: Int, val name: String, val quantity: Int, val unitPrice: BigDecimal)


    fun totalDailySales(orders: List<Order>) : Map<DayOfWeek, Int> {
        val map: MutableMap<DayOfWeek, Int>? = mutableMapOf(
            Pair(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, 0),
            Pair(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, 0),
            Pair(DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, 0),
            Pair(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY, 0),
            Pair(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY, 0),
            Pair(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY, 0),
            Pair(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, 0)
        )
        for (order in orders) {
            val dayOfWeek = order.creationDate.dayOfWeek
            var quantity = 0

            map?.put(dayOfWeek, quantity)
        }
        return map!!
    }

}
```

So the issues I am facing right now are 2 -

1) How can I increment the value of each pair when it is the corrent DayOfWeek? I don't want to replace, I want to add it to the last value.

2) When returning the Map, I do not want to return the DayOfWeeks that have the value of 0. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated answer (also thanks to [Freek de Bruijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1694043/freek-de-bruijn)), with some test code.

I think it would be something like this:

```
fun totalDailySales(orders: List<Order>) : Map<DayOfWeek, Int> =
    orders.groupBy { it.creationDate.dayOfWeek }
        .mapValues { it.value.flatMap { it.orderLines } }
        .mapValues { it.value.map { it.quantity } }
        .mapValues { it.value.sum() }
```

`groupBy` creates a `Map` where the values are of type `List<Order>`, so you need to call a few steps to convert these values to `Int`. First we use `flatMap` to convert `List<Order>` to `List<OrderLine>` (`map` would convert to `List<List<OrderLine>>`). Then we use `map` to get the quantities out of `List<OrderLine>`, and finally `sum()` to add up all those quantities.

```
val orders = listOf(
    Order(
        2,
        LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(2),
        listOf(
                OrderLine(5, "monitor", 10, 200.toBigDecimal()),
                OrderLine(4, "keyboard", 5, 50.toBigDecimal())
        )
    )

)

println(totalDailySales(orders))
```

This results in the output:

```
{FRIDAY=15}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a modified version of [the elegant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59011238/1694043) provided by [Arjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729539/arjan), with some test code.

**Updated** the answer after the comment from [Alon Shlider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8943516/alon-shlider) --  now counting all order item quantities grouped by day of the week:

```
fun totalDailySales(orders: List<Order>): Map<DayOfWeek, Int> =
    orders.groupBy { it.creationDate.dayOfWeek }
        .mapValues { sumItemQuantities(it.value) }

fun sumItemQuantities(orders: List<Order>) =
    orders.flatMap { it.orderLines.map { line -> line.quantity } }.sum()

fun main() {
    val orders = listOf(
        Order(
            1,
            LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(2),
            listOf(
                OrderLine(6, "laptop", 28, 1200.toBigDecimal())
            )
        ),
        Order(
            2,
            LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1),
            listOf(
                OrderLine(496, "VR headset", 6, 400.toBigDecimal())
            )
        )
    )

    println(totalDailySales(orders))
}
```

Output:

```
{FRIDAY=28, SATURDAY=6}
```

With this approach, Kotlin functions do the grouping and counting for you. The groupBy function creates a map from DayOfWeek to a list of orders (grouping all orders with the same day of week in a list). The mapValues function transforms that map by replacing the lists with the result of the sumItemQuantities function (for each list).

In the for loop in your code, you can retrieve the current quantity for a specific day (or use zero if it isn't set yet), increase it by the right amount and then store it. To return only the map entries with non zero values, you could filter (return totalsPerDay.filter { it.value > 0 }) or start with an empty map. This is your function with some changes:

```
fun totalDailySales(orders: List<Order>): Map<DayOfWeek, Int> {
    val totalsPerDay = mutableMapOf<DayOfWeek, Int>()

    for (order in orders) {
        val dayOfWeek = order.creationDate.dayOfWeek
        val currentQuantity = totalsPerDay[dayOfWeek] ?: 0

        // This is not the best way to increment by the sum of the order
        // item quantities...
        val orderItemQuantities = sumItemQuantities(listOf(order))
        totalsPerDay[dayOfWeek] = currentQuantity + orderItemQuantities
    }

    return totalsPerDay
}
```

Output after calling it:

```
println(OrdersAnalyzer().totalDailySales(orders))

{FRIDAY=28, SATURDAY=6}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. your solution, though, does not give the correct answer. It calculates how many times each day has been mentioned, the wanted result is calculating the total quantity for that day.

Comment: @AlonShlider You mean the total sum of the quantities for all order lines?

Comment: @Arjan yeah, that's what I mean

Comment: @AlonShlider You're welcome. I've updated my answer as well. Nice joint effort... :-)